Error when updating empty content type properties via CustomXmlParts
Im currently developing a VSTO Word AddIn in C#.
Properties that come from SharePoint (ContentTypeProperties) are stored in a customXmlPart with this namespace Uri: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties"
I already read and update all these properties.
This is the method how I update a property:
public static bool UpdateContentTypeProperty(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    // Update the node's text if the property value is not null or whitespace
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyValue))
    {
        Logger.Warn($"Property {propertyName} value is null or whitespace.");
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        var doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        var customXMLParts = doc.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties");

        if (customXMLParts.Count <= 0)
            return false;

        foreach (CustomXMLPart part in customXMLParts)
        {
            var node = part.SelectSingleNode($"//*[local-name()='{propertyName}']");

            if (node != null)
            {
                // Only works if the property already has a value, else it will throw an exception
                node.Text = propertyValue;
                Logger.Info($"Property {propertyName} updated to value {propertyValue}.");
                return true;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception($"Property {propertyName} not found in custom XML parts.");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}


This is the case if the property already contains a value (working fine):
Before:
<Doc-Template-Name xmlns="501d336e-520f-475f-a88e-1742c35e8566">{template-name}</Doc-Template-Name>


After: 
<Doc-Template-Name xmlns="501d336e-520f-475f-a88e-1742c35e8566">Example Template</Doc-Template-Name>

Here comes the problem. If I try to update an empty property using the method above, word can no longer read any properties from this customXmlPart.
This is the case when the property does not yet contain a value before the update. After this update, Word can no longer read all properties from this CustomXmlPart because the file is broken or something similar.
Before:
<Doc-Version xmlns="501d336e-520f-475f-a88e-1742c35e8566" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"></Doc-Version>


After: 
<Doc-Version xmlns="501d336e-520f-475f-a88e-1742c35e8566" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true">TestValue</Doc-Version>

This is the error that Word displays on the File--> Information page:
Sorry for the German text, the error says: "Error: The server properties in this file
cannot be displayed."


What I have already tried:
Up to this point, I have used the workaround that all properties already have a placeholder. However, this is not a nice solution.
I have already tried to address the attribute via node.Attributes in order to possibly set the xsi:nil attribute to false or delete it. However, the .Count method already returns 0.
var AttrCount = node.Attributes.Count;


Feel free to ask questions if you don't understand something. Thank you very much for your help!

Edit:
I added this to the method to set the xsi:nil attribute to false.
var xmlPart = DeleteXsiNilAttribute(part, propertyName);

part.Delete();
customXMLParts.Add(xmlPart);

The same error still happens, but after saving the file to a local location, the problem is solved. Seems like Word Refreshes something. Is there another way of forcing that besides saving the file?

I've only just been able to restore my (old) copy of SP and explore what happens when updating the properties from VBA. First, here I don't experience the problems that you did (in your previous Question about this) when using Document.ContentTypeProperties to inspect and also set the values of properties. I don't know why there's a difference...

...Second, for a nillable property, the xsi:nil="true" attribute is always present if the property value is "" (i.e. empty). Starting from that situation, I have to remove the attribute before I set a non-empty value, or I see an error. Third, if the property value is non-empty when I start, the xsi:nil attribute is never present, and starting from that situation, if I set the property value to empty ("") Word automatically adds the xsi:nil="true" attribute. I haven't yet seen the problems you describe when re-opening the file, but will have a further look.
